# Can you instantiate a Python HTTP server without it listening?

Tags: python-3.x, httpserver

My environment is Python 3.7 on Windows 10.  I'm working on (very) lightweight HTTP server app, whose main purpose is to test mobile-computer applications that perform HTTP POST requests.  I've found the Python docs and several other sources that explain the basics of using the `http.server` module, so it's no sweat to get a functioning server.

There's one detail though I'm having difficulty with.  I've found by experiment that an `HTTPServer` instance doesn't wait until you call the `serve_forever()` method to start listening.  Instead, it begins listening on the specified port as soon as you instantiate it.  If you try (e.g.) this small script:

```
import time
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        pass

h1 = HTTPServer(('', 10123), MyHandler)
print('Server instantiated')

while (True):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    pass
```

It does nothing but instantiate the server, but a check on the local machine shows that the script results in port 10123 being bound and listened on:

```
C:\Dev_Python\HTTPServer>netstat -anp tcp

Active Connections

Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
TCP    0.0.0.0:10123          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

I've found on further searching of the docs that I can 'undo' this listen by accessing the class's `socket` object:

```
h1.socket.close()
```

...but I'd rather the server just didn't start listening in the first place, until I want it to actually start doing so.

**So the question is:  Is there a way to override this behavior, and instantiate the server while delaying it from listening on the port?**

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why do you want to delay listening?

Comment: I'm using the HTTP server as a host emulator, to test a mobile-computer app.  So among the test cases I want to hit are connectivity issues -- e.g. mobile-computer app tries to connect to submit a GET/POST/whatever, but the host is unavailable or just not listening.  This lets me make sure the mobile app handles that scenario gracefully, e.g. with a reasonable timeout and an understandable error message for the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is *bind_and_activate* keyword argument, with the value of *True* by default, which allows you to control newly created socket binding and activation.

Try:

```
...
h1 = HTTPServer(('', 10123), MyHandler, bind_and_activate=False)
...
```

you can bind and activate it later:

```
...
try:
    h1.server_bind()
    h1.server_activate()
except:
    h1.server_close()
    raise
...
```

Comment: Works perfectly.  From here I can just access the `h1.socket` object and use the normal `bind/listen/close` methods to control whether the server is listening or not.